# trying to understand some codes related to readyState in js

Tags: javascript

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.onreadystatechange = WaitForComplete;

        function WaitForComplete () {
            console.log ("The state of the document: " + document.readyState);
        }

        function OnLoad () {
            console.log ("The document has been loaded.");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="OnLoad ()">
</body>
```

In firefox->console, it shows:

```
The state of the document: interactive
The state of the document: complete
The document has been loaded.
```

Question:

why every time I run script in firefox, it only shows `interactive` and `complete`? how about the other states: `uninitialized`,`loading`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the the states: `uninitialized,loading...` because you are using the `onreadystatechange` function and not checking the upper both states.

And `onreadystatechange` works when the document is in the state interactive or complete and at the states loading or uninitialized it will not call.

to getting the loading state you need to add the code:

`document.write(document.readyState);`

at the starting of script without using the `onreadystatechange`.

And the `uninitialized` state you cann't execute any javascript and can not get that state.